# Using Gitlab CD and Docker

Tags: git, docker, gitlab, continuous-deployment

This post was also made on [/r/Gitlab](https://www.reddit.com/r/gitlab/comments/5ptqc5/using_gitlab_cd_with_docker/) and [/r/Docker](https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/5ptsaa/using_gitlab_cd_with_docker/)

I'm pretty new to Gitlab, but I am absolutely loving the all in one nature of it and I really have no idea why it is not more popular. I am hosting a private project for my personal website on Gitlab.com and I have been trying to figure out how I can setup Gitlab CD to auto deploy my master branch to a docker hosted as a DigitalOcean Droplet. Here is my optimal workflow, keep in mind, I am more in need of help for the continuous deployment part than the testing part.

1. Make Changes to git on a branch
2. On every commit push, tests are run
3. Once I am ready to merge into master, I open a merge request and tests run again.
4. I then merge and the master branch is updated, this next part is what I need help with.
5. The docker server updates to the latest version and continues serving.
6. Cycle repeats, Change, Test, Merge, Deploy, Repeat.

I need help writing the .gitlab-ci.yml file that will update the docker server only on changes to master, and make sure the newest version of master is being served. I guess my biggest question is, how do I get my docker server to auto update to the latest version of master?

More info if needed:

- My website is run using Go
- It only requires one container
- I push updates to master once a day at most

Thanks, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you find the right gitlab-ci.yml config?